# What will happen if i type ctrl - c on the terminal

Tags: server, c

I got this program my friend sent me. And were both new at ubuntu and she asked me what will happen if we enter ctrl-c on the terminal

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void catch(int signo) {
    printf("Signal %d caught\n", signo);
    sleep(2);
}

int main() {
    int i;
    struct sigaction act;
    act.sa_flags = 0;
    act.sa_handler = catch;
    sigfillset(&(act.sa_mask));
    if (sigaction(SIGINT, &act, NULL) != 0) {
        perror("sigaction");
        exit(1);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        printf("sleep %d ....\n", i);
        sleep(1);
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Why don’t you just try?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/890591/why-doesnt-ctrl-c-kill-the-terminal-itself

Comment: compile, link, run, enter <ctrl-c> watch what happens.

Comment: the posted code does not compile.  it is missing the statement: `#include <unistd.h>` for the `sleep()` function  it is missing the statement: `#include <stdlib.h>` for the `exit()` function

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding, 1)  consistently indent the code.  indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest using 4 spaces for each indent level. 2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line

Comment: there are many functions that should not be called in a signal handler `printf()` and `sleep()` are two of those functions that should not be called in a signal handler

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`,at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use `-Wconversion -std=gnu11` )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What will happen is:

- your terminal will send the `SIGINT` (interrupt) signal
- your process will intercept the signal and pass its numeric value `2` to your `catch` function which will print `Signal 2 caught`
- having intercepted and processed the signal, the program will continue with the main print/sleep loop

For example

```
sleep 0 ....
sleep 1 ....
sleep 2 ....
sleep 3 ....
sleep 4 ....
^CSignal 2 caught
sleep 5 ....
sleep 6 ....
sleep 7 ....
```

You will be able to kill the program by sending a `SIGKILL` signal e.g. by suspending the process using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> and then typing `pkill myprog` (where `myprog` is the name of your compiled executable version of the code).

```
The signals SIGKILL and SIGSTOP cannot be caught, blocked, or ignored.
```

See `man 7 signal` for more information on signals and signal handling.

Answer (score 0):

`Control+C` (control character intr) sends SIGINT which will interrupt the application. Usually causing it to abort, but this is up to the application to decide.